# Example of random variables $X$ and $Y$ where $X \neq Y$, but $X = Y$ almost surely

Tags: probability-theory

I was reading some notes on probability theory and the author stated that it is possible to have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ where $X \neq Y$, but $X = Y$ almost surely. This intrigues me. What is an example of two random variables with these properties? Even a contrived example would help me better understand almost sure equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider for example $\Omega  = [0,1]$, $P$ being the Lebesgue measure,
and the random variables $$
X(\omega) = \omega
\\
Y(\omega) = \begin{cases}
\omega &\text{if} & \omega < 1
\\
0 &\text{if} & \omega = 1
\end{cases}
$$

$$
P(X\neq Y) = P(\omega = 1) = 0
$$

Comment: Ah, okay, it really is that simple!